# Decoding decimal to binary information in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've a question on decoding decimal to binary values in PySpark. 
This is how I was doing it in plain python:

```
a = 28
b = format(a, "09b")
print(b)

-> 000011100
```

Here is an expample DataFrame I would like to transform:

```
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, b='28', c='11', d='foo'),
                            Row(a=2, b='28', c='44', d='bar'),
                            Row(a=3, b='28', c='22', d='foo')])

|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1| 28| 11|foo|
|  2| 28| 44|bar|
|  3| 28| 22|foo|
+---+---+---+---+
```

And I want the column "b" to be decoded to:

```
|  a|        b|  c|  d|
+---+---------+---+---+
|  1|000011100| 11|foo|
|  2|000011100| 44|bar|
|  3|000011100| 22|foo|
+---+---------+---+---+
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With `bin` and `lpad` function to reach same output**

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark.shell import spark

df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, b='28', c='11', d='foo'),
                            Row(a=2, b='28', c='44', d='bar'),
                            Row(a=3, b='28', c='22', d='foo')])

df = df.withColumn('b', f.lpad(f.bin(df['b']), 9, '0'))
df.show()
```

**With UDF**

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark.shell import spark

df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, b='28', c='11', d='foo'),
                            Row(a=2, b='28', c='44', d='bar'),
                            Row(a=3, b='28', c='22', d='foo')])


@f.udf()
def to_binary(value):
    return format(int(value), "09b")


df = df.withColumn('b', to_binary(df['b']))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---------+---+---+
|  a|        b|  c|  d|
+---+---------+---+---+
|  1|000011100| 11|foo|
|  2|000011100| 44|bar|
|  3|000011100| 22|foo|
+---+---------+---+---+
```

Comment: Thank you, works fine. If I have for example 500 millions of data rows, won't it decrease the cluster computing (still reading on this)? Usually people say to avoid 'udf' ...

Comment: Yes, you're right, always avoid udfs with large dataframes. In this case, I'll update my answer without udfs